# Equation does not show properly

Tags: presentations

Try this equation in latex using the following command

```
$μ\textsubscript{ι}=E(Y\textsubscript{i} )$
```

However, I can see the equation in the compiler as μ and ι are not latin characters.

What command is it appropriate to see the function?

Comment: If you're using XeTeX or LuaTeX it should work out of the box. If you're using pdfTeX you can replace `μ` by `\mu` and `ι` by `\iota` and it should also work. And whatever you are using, **`\text`** `subscript{...}` is for text, not maths. In math mode use `_{...}`. This should work anywhere `$\mu_\iota=E(Y_i)$`.

Answer (score 1):

In line with @Phelype in math mode you should use:

```
$\mu_{\iota}=E(Y_{i})$
```

and you'll get

[image]